# Mounting the Live-USB partition

Tags: partitioning, live-usb, read-only, live-environment

It is possible to mount the partition where the ISO extracted *(Or we can say the root partition of a Live-USB )* not as Read-only but as read/write-able partition ?

Answer (score 0):

you could try to make a partition, and use ubuntu cd on start up and run repaire broken packged, and in grub bootloader menu run shell, and type.

chroot /
mount (name of usb like hd2) (name of partition like /dev/sda)
gpart and make the partition on the usb as /root

and it might work fine.

Comment: I'm asking about Live-USB root partition (The partition where we extract the ISO of the Ubuntu if you see it from Windows) not about other partition or pacakages.But thankyou anyway